# Minikube suddenly started using Virtualbox instead of HyperV

Tags: virtualbox, minikube, hyper-v

I have Hyperv enabled on my Mindows machine as well as Virtualbox installed.

I was able to run Minikube command:

> minikube start --cpus 6 --memory 20g --disk-size=50g

It would run without any error, using hyperV driver by default .

But now suddenly, it has started showing the below error:

> minikube start --cpus 6 --memory 20g --disk-size=50g
>
> - minikube v1.30.1 on Microsoft Windows 11 Enterprise 10.0.22621.1848 Build 22621.1848
> - Using the virtualbox driver based on existing profile ! You cannot change the CPUs for an existing minikube cluster. Please first delete
>   the cluster.
> - Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
> - Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=3, Memory=20480MB, Disk=51200MB) ... ! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create:
>   precreate: This computer is running Hyper-V. VirtualBox won't boot a
>   64bits VM when Hyper-V is activated. Either use Hyper-V as a driver,
>   or disable the Hyper-V hypervisor. (To skip this check, use
>   --virtualbox-no-vtx-check)
> - Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=3, Memory=20480MB, Disk=51200MB) ...
> - Failed to start virtualbox VM. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create: precreate: This computer is running Hyper-V.
>   VirtualBox won't boot a 64bits VM when Hyper-V is activated. Either
>   use Hyper-V as a driver, or disable the Hyper-V hypervisor. (To skip
>   this check, use --virtualbox-no-vtx-check)
>
> X Exiting due to PR_VBOX_HYPERV_64_BOOT: Failed to start host:
> creating host: create: precreate: This computer is running Hyper-V.
> VirtualBox won't boot a 64bits VM when Hyper-V is activated. Either
> use Hyper-V as a driver, or disable the Hyper-V hypervisor. (To skip
> this check, use --virtualbox-no-vtx-check)
>
> - Suggestion: VirtualBox and Hyper-V are having a conflict. Use '--driver=hyperv' or disable Hyper-V using: 'bcdedit /set
>   hypervisorlaunchtype off'

I don't remember making any change in the system. So what can be the cause of this sudden switch from hyperV to virtualbox?

Comment: `minikube profile list` and proceed from there?

Comment: Hello @Mandroid, Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like VirtualBox and Hyper-V are having a conflict. Refer to [HyperV driver](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/v0.28.2/docs/drivers.md#hyperv-driver) that require driver plugin binaries to be present in the host PATH:**

> Hyper-v users may need to create a new external network switch as
> described [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/).
> This step may prevent a problem in which minikube start hangs
> indefinitely, unable to ssh into the minikube virtual machine. In this
> add, add the --hyperv-virtual-switch=switch-name argument to the
> minikube start command.

**If the issue still persists try the below workarounds :**

**Workaround 1 :** If you run `bcdedit` with no arguments, you should see a property called `hypervisorlaunchtype`. This will be set to off or auto.

To disable Hyper-V in order to use VirtualBox, open a command prompt as administrator and run the command: `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

To turn Hyper-V back on, run command : `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`.

**Workaround 2 :** If you want to use VirtualBox without disabling the Hyper-V on Windows: By default, VirtualBox will access Hyper-V API; if not, then **setting the paravirtualization interface** will do that. Refer **Rajkumar Maurya's** H2S Media blog on [How to use VirtualBox and Hyper-V together on Windows](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/use-virtualbox-and-hyper-v-together-on-windows-10.html) for more details.

Also refer to official Minikube documentation on hyperv [Troubleshooting](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperv/#troubleshooting).